# html Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type image/jpg:base64:

Tags: html, image, base64

This is the jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/Y6Msa/

The image doesn't appear instead, I got this in the console:

```
Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type image/jpg:base64:
```

Sorry I couldn't paste the code of the image here, because the base 64 is long so I pasted it in the a jsfiddle

many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,....
```

you are missing the 'e' - and as later worked out the jsFiddle has ":" wrong before the base64

Comment: it is jpg because the image in my case is jpg not jpeg

Comment: and modifying the jpg to jpeg in the fiddle does nothing - _Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type image/jpeg:base64_

Comment: this is a working example http://jsfiddle.net/x7Dc9/ -it will be as soon as I signin to jsfiddle

Comment: @mplungjan no the working is `image/jpg` not `image/jpeg` check the question please

Comment: @AnastasieLaurent - changing jpg to jpeg just changes the error message. What should I check in the question? / http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/9ekFA/

Comment: @mplungjan Okay I got you, I though that you thought the error message is about jpeg not jpg. the problem is that I already use that image in a different place and it is working.

Comment: I was commenting to Old Fart that his suggestion did nothing.

Comment: working jsFiddle - not using the same image as it seems to have some incorrect encoding http://jsfiddle.net/oldfart/c62sx/

Comment: how are you getting your base64 encoding from the original file?

Comment: @Oldfart thanks but the problem is not in the encoding because I am using the exact same code in another img src and it is working

Comment: @Oldfart you right, part of the problem is error encoding, I will accept your answer because you discovered that, however, the problem is still appear and I will try to solve it. many thanks +1

Comment: Nice picture of the Italian team, the ":" before base64 should be a ";" sorry for the mix-up

Comment: @Oldfart OMG yes that is right many thaaaaank :) And thanks about the picture, I like Pirlo so much. though he killed us in 2006 :)